# Get more than 100 recommendations based on seeds

Tags: spotify

Assume this call:

`https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?seed_genres=deep-house&limit=100`

You would get 100 deep house recommendations with no particular order, since the max limit is 100.

Is there a way to get more than 100, say by paginating?

Comment: not according to the documentation, so I am not sure what kind of answer you want?

Comment: A way to get more than 100 recommendations